# Reading a Unix Shell Command into a String/Linked List using pipes and fork()

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, unistd.h

I'm trying to write a program using C99/gcc/Linux(unistd.h) to take in Linux shell commands from the user, execute them, retrieve their output and store it in a dynamically sized array/string for outputting/modifying at a later date.

In my code below, I'm passing the shell commands through to this function one at a time (`char * cmd`) and I'm hoping to retrieve their output either using a linked list of characters (`node * charLinkedList`) or even a dynamically allocated string large enough to fit all the data, as some commands could return 5 characters (`pwd`) while others could return **a lot** (`cat [file]`).

I have thoroughly tested and confirmed the following is working:

- storing / retrieving / printing to the character linked list
- forking the process and having the child process execute the commands (not using pipes)
- executing the shell command and printing it to the console (not using pipes)
- executing shell commands with and without arguments of varying lengths

What is not working:

- piping the output from each command to a variable / linked list

```c
#define READPIPE 0  
#define WRITEPIPE 1
/* % Inputs %
 * char * cmd : a string containing the command
 * node * charLinkedList : a linked list of char to store the output */
void execCmd(char * cmd, node * charLinkedList) {
    int fd[2];        // fd is the pipe
    pid_t pid;        // pid is for holding the process ID

    char* shellOutput;  // shellOutput is a string to store the output in, it's
                        //> not being used in this code but I'm ok using it in place
                        //> of my character linked list (charLinkedList)

    if(pipe(fd) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr,"Pipe failed");
    }
    
    /* Logic for separating the command from it's arguments */
    int argNum = argumentCounter(cmd);   // argNum counts the arguments and returns it
    char * args[argNum + 2];            // for holding the arguments that we will be passing later on
    char ** delimArguments;             // to hold the deliminated command string

    if(argNum > 0) {                                //if there are arguments with the command
        delimArguments = stringSplitter(cmd, ' ');  //stringSplitter splits the string at a deliminer and returns it
        for (int i = 0; i < (argNum + 1); i++){     //loads the commands into an array
            args[i] = *(delimArguments + i);        // this logic has been tested and works
        }
        args[argNum + 1] = 0;                       // please ignore this spaghetti code, I'll clean
    }                                               //> it up later I promise
    
    /* Forking & executing the commands */
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == -1) {
        printf("FORK FAILED\n");
    }

    if (pid == 0) { /* Child Process */
        
        close(fd[READPIPE]); // same as close(fd[0])
        
        /* This next if/else statement is for toggling between whether or not the
         * command has arguments or not. It's a mess and I'll 100% be merging 
         * this at a later date. */

        if (argNum > 0){
            /* command with arguments */ //i.e. ls -l -a
            dup2(fd[WRITEPIPE], STDOUT_FILENO);  //duplicate the STDOUT to the write end of the pipe (fd[1])
            execvp(args[0], args);               //execute the command and it's arguments
        } else {
            /* command without argument */ //i.e. ls
            dup2(fd[WRITEPIPE], STDOUT_FILENO); //duplicate the STDOUT to the write end of the pipe (fd[1])
            execlp(cmd, cmd, NULL);             //execute the command
        }
        close(fd[WRITEPIPE]);  //if something goes wrong and the code gets to here, close the pipe
        return;      //return to int main() function; don't continue this one as the child
    } else { /* Parent Process */
        close(fd[WRITEPIPE]);       //closing the writing side of the pipe
        fcntl(fd[READPIPE], F_SETFL, fcntl(fd[READPIPE], F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK); //using fcntl to get the file descriptor of the pipe

        FILE * theOutput;                          // creating a file to point at the output
        theOutput = fdopen(fd[READPIPE], "r");     // opening the stream from the child process
        char buffer;                               // a char for grabbing output one character at a time
        while((buffer = fgetc(theOutput)) != NULL) // while we havn't hit the end of the file
        {
            addToQueue(charLinkedList, buffer);    // one by one add each character of the output to
        }                                          //> the linked list queue
        printLinkedList(charLinkedList);           //outputting the list to verify the output captured
    }
```

I tried using `read()` and `write()` functions, although I couldn't get that to work. I implemented [dup2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dup-dup2-linux-system-call/) to clone `STDOUT` to the pipe and then fought with it from there, trying to get it to work (with no success). I found [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281787/putting-output-of-execvp-into-string) suggesting doing things the way I have them currently, although I can't figure out how to get output from the file descriptor.

I've tried using both `fgetc` and `fgets` to no avail and I'm kinda stuck at this point. Is this the right way to do it or is there a better way for getting `execvp` output from a child process into a string / linked list / **variable** in the parent process?

Comment: Why overcomplicate things when [`popen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) exists? Is it because you don't want to use the default shell?

Comment: Also, why a linked list of characters to store the output? That seems counterintuitive at best. You are making every single `char` become 9 times larger by adding an unnecessary pointer next to it.

Comment: The project specifications require use of  ```exec``` system commands alongside ```fork()``` and pipes. 

For storing output I'm using a linked list of characters so I can comb through the output and pick apart things elsewhere in my code. This particular function doesn't *have* to use the linked list; it can return it as just a string. 

I've implemented a character linked list elsewhere in the code so I figured I might as well use it here as I can foresee modification to the output retrieved and it's an easy way of storing a dynamic size of data.

Comment: You should create a [mre], as the current code is impossible to run without the rest of your source code.

Comment: The nested calls to `fcntl()` are fragile; I'd not risk writing that.